# Output textarea with wp_head function

Tags: php, wordpress, textarea, meta-boxes

I'm trying to echo the value from a Metabox textarea between the head tags of my Wordpress website, so that the site owner can insert page individual scripts.

I've already created my metabox with succes:

```
<?php
$post_id_post = isset($_POST['post_ID']) ? $_POST['post_ID'] : '' ;
$post_id = isset($_GET['post']) ? $_GET['post'] : $post_id_post ;

if ( ! function_exists( 'onm_head_add_meta' ) ){
    function onm_head_add_meta(){
        $types = array( 'post', 'page', 'courses', 'wiki', 'press' );
        foreach( $types as $type ) {
            add_meta_box('head-metabox-code', __('Scripts', 'onm_textdomain' ), 'onm_sitewide_meta_box', $type, 'normal', 'low'); 
        }
    }
}
add_action("admin_init", "onm_head_add_meta");

//Create area for extra fields
if ( ! function_exists( 'onm_sitewide_meta_box' ) ){
    function onm_sitewide_meta_box( $post ){ 

        $custom = get_post_custom();
        $head_scripts = isset($custom["head_scripts"][0])?$custom["head_scripts"][0]:'';

        // We'll use this nonce field later on when saving.  
        wp_nonce_field( 'my_meta_box_nonce', 'meta_box_nonce' );
        ?>  

        <textarea name="head_scripts" type="text" class="widefat" cols="50" rows="3"/><?php echo esc_attr($head_scripts); ?></textarea>
        <p><?php _e('The code in the above textfield will be added between the <code>&lt;head&gt;&lt;/head&gt;</code> tags of the website.', 'onm_textdomain' ); ?></p>

        <?php
    }
}

if ( ! function_exists( 'onm_save_page_meta_box' ) ){
    function onm_save_page_meta_box( $post_id ){ 
        // Bail if we're doing an auto save  
        if( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) {
            return; 
        }
        // if our nonce isn't there, or we can't verify it, bail 
        if( !isset( $_POST['head_scripts'] ) || !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['meta_box_nonce'], 'my_meta_box_nonce' ) ) {
            return; 
        }
        // if our current user can't edit this post, bail  
        if( !current_user_can( 'edit_pages' ) ) {
            return;  
        }
        // now we can actually save the data        
        if( isset( $_POST['head_scripts'] ) )  {
            update_post_meta( $post_id, 'head_scripts', esc_attr( $_POST['head_scripts'] ) ); 
        }
    }
    }

add_action( 'save_post', 'onm_save_page_meta_box' );
```

Now I try to output the value from the Metabox between my head tags as follows:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'onm_wp_head' ) ){
    function onm_wp_head() {
        $head_scripts_meta = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'head_scripts' , TRUE );
        if ( $head_scripts_meta != '' ) {
            echo $head_scripts_meta, "\n";
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'onm_wp_head' );
```

But on my website this results in the output of the Metabox right after my opening body tag (take a look at my example below or [this](http://cl.ly/3J321r310502) print screen).

```
<head></head>
<body>
    "<script type="text/javascript">Test</script>"
```

Not a nice script within my head tags. It's weird because it works like a charm when I test the script as follows:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'onm_wp_head' ) ){
    function onm_wp_head() {
        $head_scripts_meta = '<script type="text/javascript">Test</script>';
        if ( $head_scripts_meta != '' ) {
            echo $head_scripts_meta, "\n";
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'onm_wp_head' );
```

I think this has to do with the textarea, isn't it? Any ideas how to solve this? Thanks already guys!

Comment: Sorry, but at least for me it isn't clear the actual output of your function. Can you provide the resulting HTML of the former piece of code? :)

Comment: Dear @FelipeElia, I've updated my question with the actual output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution after a while. I had to stripslashes before the output in the header. So my function became the following and then it worked:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'onm_script_wp_head' ) ){
    function onm_script_wp_head() {
        $head_scripts_meta = stripslashes(get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'head_scripts' , TRUE ));
        if ( $head_scripts_meta != '' ) {
            echo $head_scripts_meta, "\n";
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'onm_script_wp_head' );
```

Thanks for helping guys!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `get_the_ID()` will not work in your head (it won't work until `the_post` is called).

Modify as follows:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'onm_wp_head' ) ){
    function onm_wp_head() {
        global $post;
        $head_scripts_meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'head_scripts' , TRUE );
        if ( $head_scripts_meta != '' ) {
            echo $head_scripts_meta, "\n";
        }
    }
}

add_action( 'wp_head', 'onm_wp_head' );
```

Comment: Cale, thanks for your answer but this doesn't work. The metabox is echo'd well. But it it shows the metabox als follows: [Image](http://cl.ly/1E0C0o3t0d0M). Above my body. So it doesn't return as a real script or style line.

Comment: Hi Nick - so let's be clear:  according to your image, it does work - I solved the question you asked, yes?  Now you have discovered a follow-on issue, which is that the entries get modified so that it renders html entities instead of raw html?  If that's the case then you should ask a new question.  (All of the details about how you render the text area and how you save it are important to answer that question).

Comment: Hi Cale, Sorry for boing not clear in that case. I thought I was clear by telling that the I want the Metabox textarea between the head tags. In the current situation this isn't the case. 

But you are right, What I want is the entries to get mdofied so that it renders html entities instead of raw html.

Comment: Hi Nick - are you saying that this **does not** render between the head tags? are you sure - did you "view source"? What I believe the issues is at this point is that (a) it IS rendering between head tags (that's what `wp_head` does), and (b) because it's not inside of `<script>` tags, but rather is html entities, it's visible.  I can help resolve that issue, but it would be nice if you found this answer helpful if you could at least upvote it.

Comment: Also - per my other comment - in order to resolve this problem I really DO need to see how you are rendering the textarea and how you are saving it.  Can you edit your question with those details and let me know?

Comment: Hi cale_b, I've updated my question with the required information. As you can see it is not rendered between the head tags. Thanks for helping me.

Comment: Are you sure 'wp_head' is being called between your head tags?  Check your theme header.php file.

Comment: Scratch my last comment.  One last thing - in your function where you output the script, can you add a 'var_dump($head_scripts_meta)'?  You are right that something is off, hopefully that will tell us what.  Post the results back here

Comment: Hi cale_b, I've add 'var_dump($head_scripts_meta);' right before '$head_scripts_meta = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'head_scripts' , TRUE );' in my function.php. The results is: http://cl.ly/1d311y1p0e3j

Comment: Where did the NULL come from?  Also, a `var_dump` usually results in something like this: `string(20) "<script>blah blah</script>` - where's the rest of the var dump info?

Comment: Also - **please answer my questions**.  I'm going to stop helping if you cannot answer the questions I have asked - you've only answered SOME of them.  Review ALL of the questions posed in my comments above, and answer any that you have not yet answered.  New question: when you **view source** of the page, what does it show?  How are you looking at WHERE the script is being output - view source? Browser inspector? You cannot use the browser inspector in this case, because they "auto-correct" markup issues, so you need to **view source**